# Error: Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I was able to execute my servlet programs in eclipse or directly in portal by using startup bat and shutdown bat before. And also I already changed my port from 8080 to 8090 as 8080 was in use of oracle database.  Suddenly I got this error Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost has encountered a problem when I try to execute any servlet programs. Can anyone give me a solution for this?
I am using eclipse mars and windows 10 64bit

Comment: Hi Prabhu, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is quite difficult to understand though; can you [edit] it to describe more clearly what you were doing, and exactly what the error message was? That will make it easier for people to help you with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you people are facing the same problem , follow this procedure
1. If you people have any important servlet programs, save all the programs in a separate folder.

2.Delete all your servlet,dynamic web project programs..etc programs from the eclipse including the folder named as server.

3.And in C folder delete the Apache tomcat server too
(In short delete everything related to tomcat server)

4.Now reinstall the Apache tomcat 7.0 and go to bin folder and double click on Startup bat. 
If command prompt blinks and goes off
You have to change the path and class path in Environment variable which should contain %JAVA_HOME%

5.If your startup bat is success(Eg: Last line will show some milliseconds), server is working propery and ddouble click on shutdown bat

6.Now go to conf folder, open the server.xml and change"connection port=8080 "to  "connection port=8081 or 8099 or 8090...something like this " and save it

7.Click on startup bat .Now go to browser and type   "http://localhost:8090/" It should open tomcat server on your browser.
(WORKING OF TOMCAT IS SUCCESS)

8. Recreate your servlet folder in ua E drive or  D Drive....Now go to eclipse.. switch the workspace and open new dynamic web project--(your servlet folder name)---(generate web.xml) asusual coding. In your eclipse workspace server folder will not be there

(Integrate tomcat with eclipse again)
9.Below you will "No Servers are available,Click the link to create a new server"
Click on this---ApacheTomcat v7.0server---next---browse----C:ApacheTomcat---OK---Finish

10.Now you will see "Tomcat v7.0 server at localhost"
Right Click on this..Properties--switch location--Apply---OK

11.Again Right click on "Tomcat v7.0" --open--(scrolldown)Select "Use Tomcat I stallation"---save it   (For your confrimaation Right side you can see the port HTTP1.1    8081)

12.Run on the server